# communication between two clients in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, client-server, chat

I am trying to create a Ruby program that would send messages between two clients with the server in the middle. For example client A connects to server and client B connects to the same server and port. Client A says "How are you?" and client B says "Doing good." Kinda like a chat server. I am thinking on having the server take the message from client A and send to client B. So far I have this working client and server program that connects using a certificate. The problem I have is that my server sends back to client A and I do not know how to send to the second connection (client B).

**client**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "socket"
require "openssl"
require "thread"

host = ARGV[0]
port = Integer(ARGV[1])

socket = TCPSocket.new(host, port)
certificate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("server.crt"))
ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket)
ssl.sync_close = true
ssl.connect
if ssl.peer_cert.to_s != certificate.to_s
  stderrr.puts "Unexpected certificate"
  exit(1)
end

# Get input through the server
Thread.new {
  begin
    while server_res = ssl.gets.chomp
      puts server_res
    end
  rescue
    $stderr.puts "Error in server response loop: " + $!
  end
}
# send out the STDIN to the server
while (client_sent = STDIN.gets.chomp)
  ssl.puts client_sent 
end
```

**server**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "socket"
require "openssl"
require "thread"

port = Integer(ARGV[0])
server = TCPServer.new(port)

sslCont = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
sslCont.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("server.crt"))
sslCont.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open("server.key"))

sslServ = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLServer.new(server, sslCont)

loop {
  connection = sslServ.accept
  Thread.new {
    begin
      while (client_sent = connection.gets) do
        client_sent = client_sent.chomp
        puts "Client Sent: " + client_sent
        server_res = "Server Response: " + client_sent
        puts server_res
        connection.puts server_res
      end
    rescue
      $stderr.puts $!
    end
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the certificates actually part of your problem? If not, consider removing them from your example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Keep an array of accepted connections

  ```
  connections = []
  ```
- Keep it up to date when someone connects or disconnects

  ```
  connections << connection
  ...
  connections.delete(connection)
  ```
- When sending, you can send to all of them:

  ```
  connections.each do |conn|
    conn.puts server_res
  end
  ```
- Or just all except the current one:

  ```
  connections.each do |conn|
    next if conn == connection
    conn.puts server_res
  end
  ```
- EDIT: Moved from comments because it's important: put `connections.delete` into the `finally` clause of the `begin...rescue...finally...end` block. This way, it gets executed when connection breaks for any reason (whether naturally from breaking the `while` condition, or unnaturally by exception). What you can't do is put it outside the thread block, because then each `connection` would be taken out of `connections` as soon as it was put in.

Comment: Reading any non-trivial length of code in comments is painful, but that seems like what I had in mind. One thing I can see is wrong though: I'd have `connections.delete` in a `finally` clause; it certainly can't be outside the thread block, because it'd get deleted immediately.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. Sorry I've been trying to send you the code neatly organize, but it wont work and I cannot delete it.

Comment: It's fine. In the future, try to post any larger piece of code by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: So I still cannot make it work. Nothing has changed.  [Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/7jSs8Mjp)

Comment: `connections = []` needs to be outside the loop, or it is just emptied all the time.

Comment: Silly me. I should have thought of that. Thank you so much for your help!